# Formatting time in Android using norwegian locale returns dot and not colon as seperator

Tags: android, datetime

When formatting the local time in our app we have previously have issues on .NET with this bug: 
[.NET (3.5) formats times using dots instead of colons as TimeSeparator for it-IT culture?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7498058/net-3-5-formats-times-using-dots-instead-of-colons-as-timeseparator-for-it-it) which is fixed in .NET 4.0.

When we test Android formatting of local time we get the same error there for norwegian locale, we get the time as "21.00" while we use the period here in Norway so it should be "21:00".

```
DateFormat tf = android.text.format.DateFormat.getTimeFormat(m_activity);
```

This occurs both on Android 4.2 and 4.0.4 when I test it. Is this also a bug?

And I see Android also uses AM/PM for UK which also is a bit "unstandard"? 
[Formatting time with en_GB locale gives different results in Android and standard Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5490268/formatting-time-with-en-gb-locale-gives-different-results-in-android-and-standar)

Comment: Remember, Android isn't Java, they don't even run on the same kind of VM. Don't expect them to share common sense ;) I don't even know if it's a bug or a feature to be honest.

Comment: @ChristerNordvik : AM/PM is still very much accepted here in the UK. Most appliances with digital clocks/timers either default to 24hr system or have an option for both 12/24hr displays. TV listings on the BBC website (for example) may be in 24hr format but announcements on TV will say things like "New series starts tonight at 9pm". In other words, the 24hr clock is normal for technology but the 12hr clock is still what the humans use on a day to day basis. Sorry that doesn't help with your problem - I just thought I'd clarify that.

Comment: @Squonk You are correct and I see that Android also returns 9:00PM only if the clock is set to 12 hour clock on Android so it's 100% correct in that regard. It's only the norwegian locale that has this bug as far as I've tested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer from Google engineer:
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=42104

"As usual, my advice is not to use android.text.format.DateFormat. if you use java.text.DateFormat it'll use formats from the CLDR.

the problem with that is that it won't respect the user's 12/24-hour preference. i'm working on trying to get that information down to libcore so we can just do the right thing. (and then we can switch the duplicated API in frameworks/base over to using the libcore implementation.)"

Answer (score 0):

Why not format it yourself with http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html ?

Obviously until you get a clear answer from Google, you won't know if it's a feature or a bug, and even if it does get confirmed - God knows when it'll be fixed. They still have pending bugs from 2009!

I suggest you make a "temporary" workaround using the NumberFormat to parse certain DateFormat outputs and 'standardize' them that way. Beats waiting for google to fix this :)

Comment: Maybe because that's why _locales_ are for?

Comment: Obviously some of them are broke, and I don't see why making a (temporary) workaround would be a bad idea. It's certainly possible with this.

Comment: As a workaround for a system bug would be fine. You should include that in your answer, along with the code to distinguish whether the workaround has to be applied or not (i.e., is the current locale norwegian)...

Comment: That's what we had before. Either AM/PM (for US) or HH:mm format (rest of the world). I guess I just have to revert back to that code then. Maybe I could file a bug and hope for it to be fixed in Android 7.0 :-)

Comment: `a (temporary) workaround` posted in a 2012, yeah temporary

Comment: `They still have pending bugs from 2009!` and older ones as well... sometimes it's best not to look at their public issue tracker. @VladimirStarkov