# Why does DateTime.ToString() seem to ignore the thread current culture?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, .net-4.5, string-formatting

I have this code:

```
var ci = new CultureInfo("it-IT", false);
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = ci;
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = ci;

var format = "HH:mm\\:ssZ";
var formatted = DateTime.Now.ToString( format, ci );
```

and... formatted happens to be `09:08:32Z` on my machine which has default culture different from "Italy". [MSDN says](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that colon is a format specifier and provides a sample of how an unescaped colon is formatted as a dot with "it-IT" culture (the one I have in the code above).

In my code I have one colon character escaped and one unescaped and they are both formatted as a colon.

Why does it happen? Why is thread current culture seemingly being ignored?

Comment: Did you check the value of `ci.DateTimeFormat.TimeSeparator`? What is its value?

Comment: I tried your code on .NET 4.5 and it shows `:` as a `TimeSeparator` for `it-IT` culture. I don't see anything wrong with your code, honestly. If you set `ci.DateTimeFormat.TimeSeparator = "."`, your result will be `09.08:32Z` on .NET 4.5 version. I didn't look the older versions of it but these things _can_ be change over .NET or OS versions.

Comment: Seems related: [.NET (3.5) formats times using dots instead of colons as TimeSeparator for it-IT culture?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7498058).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The time separator for "it-IT" culture is a colon, as you can see if you check `ci.DateTimeFormat.TimeSeparator`. I guess that the MSDN documentation is wrong.

You can always manually change the time separator (`ci.DateTimeFormat.TimeSeparator = "."`) if you really need it.

**EDIT:** As stated in comments, it seems that [the time separator for the it-IT culture *was* a dot in .NET 3.5, but was changed to a colon in .NET 4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7498058/447156).

Comment: On which part MSDN is wrong exactly? I couldn't catch your point.

Comment: MSDN shows this example: `2009-06-15T13:45:30 -> . (it-IT)`. So I guess they actually meant `: (it-IT)`

Comment: Interesting. It all started with my ASP.NET service getting requests with `Accept-Language: it-IT` and formatting time with dots.

Comment: @Konamiman Oh I see. Yes, you are right about that. Since the document based on .NET Framework 4.6 and 4.5 versions, it should `:`, not `.`.

Comment: @sharptooth Looks like this `TimeSeparator` of _that_ culture [changed after .NET 3.5 version](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7498058/447156). Since you tagged with `.net-4-5`, it is normal to see it as `:`.

Comment: @SonerGönül It may so happen that somehow .NET framework 3.5 is used for some pieces of the actual production code and that's why we see dots there.