# DateTime timestamp has period instead of colon

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, datetime, datatable

I have a Datatable with two DateTime columns: date_from and date_to.

```
string dateFrom = row["date_from"].ToString();
string dateTo = row["date_to"].ToString();
```

When this code is run in a customer environment, it returns dates in the following format:

```
"2016-01-01 00.00.00"
"2016-02-01 00.00.00"
```

This string is then inserted into SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table
WHERE UPPER(status) = 'N'
AND trans_date >= {ts '1900-01-01 00.00.00' }
AND trans_date <= {ts '1900-01-01 00.00.00' }
```

When this SQL is executed it returns the error "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string."

So a quick fix for this is to run a string.Replace() where I replace period with colon:

```
dateFrom = dateFrom.Replace(".", ":");
```

However, my question is rather why the date is returned with periods as the timestamp separator and not colons?

I have created this test on my local machine, but unfortunately for this scenario it returns a correct representation of the DateTime string:

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
table.Columns.Add("date", typeof(DateTime));

DataRow row = table.NewRow();
row["date"] = DateTime.Now;
table.Rows.Add(row);

DateTime date = DateTime.Parse(table.Rows[0]["date"].ToString());
```

My guess so far would be that it has something to do with the customers culture, but I would really appreciate input from someone who has experience with this so I can give feedback to the customer about why this happened in the first place.

It might just be a coincidence, but it is worth mentioning that this only happens for users with Windows 10. Everyone using Windows 7 does not get this error.

Comment: Why are you using string concatenation with SQL, why not use parameters? If you do that then it does not matter what the culture is set to.

Comment: You could use a custom date string to avoid local culture problems : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx#timeSeparator e.g date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd H:mm:ss")

Comment: I found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7498058/net-3-5-formats-times-using-dots-instead-of-colons-as-timeseparator-for-it-it

Comment: Thank you for the input about parameterization and using a custom ToString(). I will implement this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you says, this is about customer's culture. Specifically `CultureInfo.DateTimeFormat`.

This property returns a `DateTimeFormatInfo` object that defines the culturally appropriate format of displaying dates and times.

This object have a property `TimeSeparator` that gets or sets the string that separates the components of time, that is, the hour, minutes, and seconds.

You can setup this property to specify a separator like `:`.

However a better approach is passing a specific culture to `ToString()` method like `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` (culture-independent):

```
string dateFrom = ((DateTime)row["date_from"]).ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
string dateTo = ((DateTime)row["date_to"]).ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

or use your own format:

```
string dateFrom = ((DateTime)row["date_from"]).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
string dateTo = ((DateTime)row["date_to"]).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

Comment: HH rather than hh, might be better - the latter is 12 hour clock

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer Arturo, it clarifyed my question!